# Javascript Replace String Dot Notation with Square Brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a string in dot notation with square brackets:

```
emergency.1.phone.2
```

Should convert to:

```
emergency[1][phone][2]
```

I'm trying to make it dynamic so it will convert the string regardless of how many dots there are.

Comment: `emergency['1']['phone']['2']`? ... but what do you mean with dynamic? Explain a little bit more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this by using the string `.replace` method with a regex with a special replacement function.

The regex is `/\.(.+?)(?=\.|$)/g`, which looks for:

- a literal `.`, followed by
- anything, until:
- another literal `.` or the end of the string

Then, you can specify a function which takes the captured string and puts it in brackets, and use that as the replacer.

Example:

```js
const dots = "emergency.1.phone.2"

// Should convert to:
// emergency[1][phone][2]

console.log(dots.replace(/\.(.+?)(?=\.|$)/g, (m, s) => `[${s}]`))
```

Comment: Good good approach `(:` +1

Comment: Simple, elegant and efficient, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
const originalString = 'emergency.1.phone.2'
const desiredString = originalString
  .split('.')
  .reduce((fullPath, arg) => fullPath + `['${arg}']`)

console.log(desiredString)

// logs: emergency['1']['phone']['2']
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the function `reduce`.

```js
let str = "emergency.1.phone.2",
    arr = str.split('.'),
    result = arr.reduce((a, s, i) => i === 0 ? s : a + `[${s}]`);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```